# How to delete data with httpDelete via JSON

Tags: android, json, http

How can i delete one particular row in the http database? I am thinking to use httpDelete like httpGet, but it doesnt work.

This is my code of post and delete. I am affair that by using that deleteMarkerData(), I delete the entire table instead of just one.

```
public void postCarData() {
    Thread t = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost( CAR_URI);
            try {
              List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(5);
              nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", String.valueOf(lat)));
              nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", ""));
              nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("price", String.valueOf(lon)));
              nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("product", UserLogin.accountName ));
              nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("action", "put"));
              post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

              HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
              BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
              String line = "";
              while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {    Log.d(TAG, line);       }
            } catch (IOException e) {   Log.d(TAG, "IOException while trying to conect to GAE"); }
        }
    };
    t.start();
}

public void deleteCarData() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpDelete delete = new HttpDelete( CAR_URI );
    client.execute(delete);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're asking a question about why the server's DELETE method behaves as it does whereas you have posted a question with code for a client of the DELETE method. There is no way to answer this question without knowing what the server behind CAR_URI does